# How to remove previous ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, viewcontroller

Seeking help.

My Project:
i make a book for children.
Every page is a custom ViewController. 
On every Page i have a button for next and previous Page.
When the NextPage-Button is pressed I "switch"/add a ViewController in the AppDelegate like this:

```
- (void)goToNextPage2 {
self.view2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
view2.view.frame = CGRectMake(769, 0, 768, 1024);
[window addSubview:view2.view];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
view2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

How and where do i remove the previous Viewcontroller?
In this case it would be ViewController1.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance
Planky

Comment: Why would you want to 'remove' the previous view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't provide much information...
Anyway, that might help.

In your animation code:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
```

And add that to remove the ViewController:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [self.view1.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.view1 = nil;
}
```

Comment: i have not enough reputation,sorry. but when i have enough i will. promise!